# Extending and interface in TypeScript and setting it equal to something (Generics)?

Tags: typescript

I encountered a type declaration in the library `react-router` that is causing me a lot of trouble to understand:

```
export interface RouteComponentProps<
    Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {},
    C extends StaticContext = StaticContext,
    S = H.LocationState
> {
    ...
}
```

The first line of the generics is the hardest for me. And I would love some help with this...

```
Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {}
```

As far as I understand it, we are taking some interface called `Params` as an argument and then we make every element in that interface optional. So, we are manipulating the passed in interface.

I am also having a lot of trouble understanding the equal sign `= {}`. What does it mean to extend an interface and setting it equal to something? Thanks!

Comment: You're not "manipulating the passed in interface", but rather saying that whatever type you pass as that first type param must extend `{ [K in keyof Params]?: string }`. The `= {}` is just providing a default value for that type parameter- so if you do not pass any type param, it'll default to `{}`.

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer! One small question: why is there a question mark behind `[K in keyof Params]?` - ? is this so the compiler wont complain when `Params` is empty?

Answer (score 3):

### Explanations of Params generic

`Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {}`

It means that `Params` needs to be an object(key->value map) which can have all properties optional and all these properties will be type of `string`. `{}` means default type when we don't put the argument. I said properties can be, but not must be optional, as `extends` you can read as `is assignable to`, so for example object with all/some properties required will fit that requirement. Consider:

```
// function which has Params property
const f = <Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {}>(p: Params) => p;
type A = {
    a: string // required field
}
f({ a: 'str' } as A) // is ok, pass the interface
type B = {
    b?: string // not required field
}
f({} as B) // is ok pass the interface
```

So really `Params` mean any object with string properties, no matter required or not. It means also that empty object `{}` can be used as we don't require any property to be there.

### Explanation of other generic types

Next lines are rather simple:

```
C extends StaticContext = StaticContext
```

Type `C` needs to be assignable to type `StaticContext`, so needs to have all properties of `StaticContext` if we assume its an object

```
S = H.LocationState
```

Type `S` can be anything, but if will not be provided, will be as default `H.LocationState`